# Dynamic input generation with Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-form

Good morning,

I have a multilingual backend application which has to support `n` languages.
The languages are stored in a database and can be added at any moment.
Now for my backend functionality, I need to dynamically generate `<input>` fields based on the languages stored in my db, for example:

> 1. German: `<input type="text" id="title_de">`
> 2. English `<input type="text" id="title_en">`
> 3. Italian `<input type="text" id="title_it">`
> 4. ...

I currently add them like this using `Zend_Form`:

```
  foreach($languages as $language){
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("title_" . $language->getPrefix());
    $title->setLabel("Title " . $language->getPrefix())
      ->setRequired(true)
    $this->addElements(array($title));
  }
```

And this is how I save the fields to my DB using Doctrine:

```
//get language-dependent title and write to DB
  foreach($languages as $language){
    $title->setLanguage($language);
    $title->setContent($form->getValue("title_" . $language->getPrefix()));
    $touristArea->addTitle($title);

    //persist and flush
    $em->persist($touristArea);
    $em->flush();            
  }
```

Anyway, as I have many language dependent fields (Titles, Captions, etc.), the code to process the form can get quite nasty and I always have to query the language table in my DB in order to know what inputs have been generated.
Is there a better way to do this? Like with an array of inputs or something like that? Thanks for any inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Zend_Translate` component
First of all create source file with translations -> 
**Creating Array source files**

Array source files are plain arrays. But you have to define them manually since there is no tool to aid this. But because they are so simple, it's the fastest way to look up messages if your code works as expected. It's generally the best adapter to get started with translation business.

```
$english = array(
    'message1' => 'message1',
    'message2' => 'message2',
    'message3' => 'message3');

$german = array(
    'message1' => 'Nachricht1',
    'message2' => 'Nachricht2',
    'message3' => 'Nachricht3');

$translate = new Zend_Translate(
    array(
        'adapter' => 'array',
        'content' => $english,
        'locale'  => 'en'
    )
);

$translate->addTranslation(array('content' => $german, 'locale' => 'de'));
```

Since release 1.5 it is also supported to have arrays included within an external file. You just have to provide the filename and Zend_Translate will automatically include it and look for the array. See the following [page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.sourcecreation.html) for more info about source files

Then take a look for **Internationalization of Zend_Form**

In order to initialize I18n in forms, you will need either a Zend_Translate object or a Zend_Translate_Adapter object, as detailed in the Zend_Translate documentation. Once you have a translation object, you can attach a translator to a specific form instance or to specific elements using their setTranslator() methods:

```
// Tell *this* form instance to use a specific translate adapter; it
// will also be used to translate validation error messages for all
// elements:
$form->setTranslator($translate);

// Tell *this* element to use a specific translate adapter; it will
// also be used to translate validation error messages for this
// particular element:
$element->setTranslator($translate);
```

Detailed guide is [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.i18n.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I have come across `Zend_Translate` earlier, I'll check it out.

Comment: do you think i should translate the id's of my `<input>` using `Zend_Translate` rather than setting them manually like `$title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("title_" . $language->getPrefix());`?

Comment: Since you are using Zend Framework, using `Zend_Translate` only gives you advantage over manually performed actions and gives bigger flexibility to your application. You will say thx to yourself later.

Comment: So `Zend_Translate` seems more like a simple tool for translating string outputs for a multilingual application. Although that's fine and I will definetely need that, i don't think it's a solution for my initial problem involving creation and processing of input fields depending on how many languages are stored in a DB table...

Comment: It seems that it's hard for you to understand, that you need to create source with translations from database (you can even cache it) and then use source for single form without doing mess as you do.